# How to make this dictionary/key python code work

Tags: python, function, csv, dictionary, key

I am trying to make a function that takes a threshold and determines which names from a csv file of song names and their lyrics that contain human names and the function
should create a csv file named outputfile that contains the number of distinct names, the name of
the song and the artist.

```
import csv

def findName(thresh, outputFile):
  dictNames={}
  with open('allNames.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
      if row["name"] in dictNames:
        dictNames[row["name"]] +=1
      else:
        dictNames[row["name"]]=1
  
  with open(outputFile, "w", newline='') as outfile:
    headers= ["song", "artist", "year"]
    writer=csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    for key, val in dictNames.items():
      if val>= thresh:
        writer.writerow({key: val})

    csvfile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

Comment: That's nice. What is your specific question?

Comment: You don't need to close files opened with a context manager

Comment: the function seems to not be working

Comment: How is it not working / what does it do instead? Describe the problem in as much detail as you can. Every bit of info you give can help us find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What's the rationale for not using Pandas here?

Not sure I fully understand your question, but I'm thinking something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('allNames.csv')

#partition df after threshold
df['index'] = df.index

def partition_return(threshold, df):
    df = df.loc[df['index'] >= threshold].reset_index(drop=true)
    df = df[['song', 'artist', 'year]]
    df['count_names_dist'] = len(df['artist'].unique())
    df.to_csv('outfile.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! unfortunately we are not allowed to use pandas right now which is why im struggling lol